# Milky Motorcycle Engine Oil

Tags: engine, motorcycle, oil, water

Good day,

I recently replaced the engine oil and it was milky. Water mixed with the oil. Is there any sense in the following process?

1. Drain all the milky oil.
2. Fill the engine with WD-40.
3. Spin the back many times to get the parts moving.
4. Drain the WD-40.
5. Fill with normal engine oil.

Kind regards,

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the process to:

```
Drain all the milky oil.
Fill the engine with fresh oil.
Run the engine for 10 minutes, switch off and let oil drain for 10 minutes.
Drain that oil.
Fill with normal engine oil.
```

Comment: Normal engine oil can already displace water?

Comment: Milky oil is water and oil mixed so drain it, also oil floats on water so when you drain it, the first out will be the water...

Comment: Also, it may be worth finding why water got into the system in the first place. Is it a water cooled engine?

Comment: It's an air cooled engine. I think the gasket for the fuel tank is brittle now. Then it rained a lot this month. Then water got into the carburetor. I made the mistake of thinking the engine was just cold and let it run. Then it stopped running. This was 16 days ago. I only got to doing the oil changes yesterday. I hope the engine is still okay enough.